# Pause Video in modal on click outside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pause video when user click outside modal area, for now pause works only if user click on close button. I want to pause video when its not on screen.

```js
  autoPlayYouTubeModal();

  //FUNCTION TO GET AND AUTO PLAY YOUTUBE VIDEO FROM DATATAG
  function autoPlayYouTubeModal() {
      var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
      trigger.click(function () {
          var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
              videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-theVideo"),
              videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1";
          $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
          $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
              $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
          });
      });
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-theVideo="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">VIDEO</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div>
                    <iframe width="100%" height="350" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is example Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/h8daS/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this can be tried**

```
 $('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('#videoModal .close').trigger('click')
      })
```